# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.countryselect/com.example.countryselect.OfferSelect}

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am developing an application that starts `MainActivity` with and checks if user is logged in shared preferences, if he is logged in it takes him to `OfferSelect` activity.

the problem is it stops at `setContentView(R.layout.main)` giving error

```
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.countryselect/com.example.countryselect.OfferSelect}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:273)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:225)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at com.example.countryselect.OfferSelect.onCreate(OfferSelect.java:158)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  ... 11 more
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  ... 22 more
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout$1
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.<init>(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:91)
10-27 22:34:38.850: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  ... 25 more`
```

my `OfferSelect` `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getOverflowMenu();
    try
    {
        startLongRunningOperation();
    }
     catch (Exception e){ 
            }
        }
}
```

My main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/main_layout4"  >
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
            <requestFocus />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[android](http://tinypic.com/r/20l1kb6/8)

[java build](http://tinypic.com/r/20571js/8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VM is not able to find `android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout`

Check if your apcompat_v7 is correctly imported. Also delete the android-support-v4.jar from your libs folder. Different version of this support library could also cause this problem.

Comment: I think it is imported correctly, but i can't upload a screenshot, i don't have enough reputation

Comment: you could use some other free service to upload the pic and post your link here....

Comment: Delete support library jar from your project's libs folder. Keep everything as is.